# Two unrelated questions: (1) meaning of "_____-speak" (2) placement and referent of "at all"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> (1.1)It is widely known that any English conversation begins with
>   The Weather. (1.2)Such a fixation with the weather ***finds*** expression in
>   Dr. Johnson's famous comment that "When two English meet, their first
>   talk is of weather." (1.3)Though Johnson's observation is as accurate
>   now as it was over two hundred years ago, most commentators fail to
>   come up with a convincing explanation for this ***English weather-speak***.
>
> (2.1)Bill Bryson, for example, concludes that, as the English weather
>    is ***not at all*** exciting, the obsession with it can hardly be
>   understood. (2.2)He argues that "To an outsider,the most striking
>   thing about the English weather is that there is not ***very much of it***."
>   (2.3)Simply, the reason is that the unusual and unpredictable weather
>   is almost unknown in the British Isles.
>
> (3.1)Jeremy Paxman, however, disagrees with Bryson, arguing that the
>   English weather is by
>   nature attractive. (3.2)Bryson is wrong, he says, because the English
>   preference for the weather has nothing to do with the natural
>   phenomena. (3.3)"The interest is less in the phenomena themselves, but
>   in uncertainty." According to him, the weather in England is very
>   changeable and uncertain and it attracts the English as well as the
>   outsider.
>
> (4.1)Bryson and Paxman stand for common misconceptions
>   about ***the weather-speak*** among the English. (4.2)Both commentators,
>   somehow, are missing the point. (4.3)The English weather conversation
>   is not really about the weather at all. (4.4)English weather-speak is
>   a system of signs, which is developed to help the speakers overcome
>   the natural reserve and actually talk to each other. (4.5)Everyone
>   knows conversations starting with weather-speak are not requests for
>   weather data. (4.6)Rather, they are routine greetings, conversation
>   starters or the blank "fillers". In other words, ***English weather-speak***
>   is a means of social bonding.

1. How to understand and parse the meaning of the phrase in bold?
2. "the English weather is not at all exciting"
   Does it mean "the English weather is not exciting at all"? If so , what does "at all" modify?

Answer (score 4):

***weather-speak*** is a noun, made by joining two words, the noun *weather* and the verb *speak.* Together it is a shortened name for the activity of speaking about the weather. In your phrase, *English* acts as an adjective, making the weather-speak particular to the *English*.

> English(adj) weather(n) is(v) *not at all* exciting(adj).

**not at all** is an idiom meaning *certainly not*, *absolutely not.* It functions as an adjective modifying *exciting*, so together the phrase means the weather in England is certainly not exciting.

> the most striking thing about the English weather is that there is not very much of it.

**not very much of it.** the pronoun *it* refers to *English weather*. *of* is a preposition expressing the relationship between *it* and *much*.  *very* is an adjective modifying *much*, *not* modifies *much* as well, so **not very much of it** means **there is not a lot of weather in England.** this may sound strange, but weather also means *types* of weather: stormy, windy, snowy, cold, hot... so the phrase actually means the weather in England doesn't change much.

I hope that helped. Please ask more questions of me if you need more help.

Comment: I'd like to add a comment on the verb *find*, which is used in an uncommon way here (*[a fixation] finds [expression]*), since *a fixation* is not a person or a living thing. The verb *find* can be used with non-living thing in a sense of *to reach* or *to arrive at*, e.g. *water finds its own level*. One familiar idiom that might be helpful for this explanation is *find its way*, e.g. *the letter found its way onto my desk somehow*.

Comment: @DamkerngT.“ the letter found its way onto my desk somehow.”，means "Someone put the letter onto my desk"?

Comment: @DamkerngT.Is it the usage of personification?

Comment: It usually implies that. But the sentence doesn't emphasize that implication, it just states that somehow I found the letter on the desk, and I don't know (or don't care) how it has arrived there. --Personification? Maybe. (I didn't think of it that way. But it seems so once you asked.)

Comment: +1 It's perhaps worth remarking that the *-speak* suffix goes back to [**Newspeak**](http://orwell.ru/library/novels/1984/english/en_app), the totalitarian politically correct English invented by George Orwell in his dystopian novel *1984*. One of its features was 'an almost complete interchangeability between different parts of speech'.

Comment: "The most striking think about the English weather is that there is not very much of it." I'm from the US so I might be wrong, but the way I see it, "there is not very much of it" is an intentionally confusing way of saying "there is not very much *notable* weather". The confusion creates humor. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: I would agree that it is an ironic turn of phrase, but that in BrE, it is acceptable.